# Jquery UI Draggable Conflict clone vs greedy

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have used the layout mentioned here: [jQueryUI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/accordion.html)
I need to drag a div from left pane to the central pane. For cross pane draggability I have used the following helper function:

```
function () { 
    return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').css('z-index',9999).show();
    }
```

But I want to use `greedy: true`, which does not work if I use the above mentioned helper function.

If I use `helper: "clone"` then `greedy` works but cross pane draggability does not.

P.S.: the div being dragged is a general div (not accordion or anything)

Edit: Demo at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/140900310/Graphical-IDE-for-C-master/index.html

I have commented the helper function now, if I uncomment then cross-pane draggable works but greedy attribute does not.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle example?

Comment: What do you mean with `cross pane draggability`?

Comment: Demo at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/140900310/Graphical-IDE-for-C-master/index.html

As stated earlier, look at constructscipt.js when I use the helper function, div from left side is draggable to the centre pane. i.e. cross-pane draggability.

Answer (score 0):

After initially hacking at it and realizing the issue was with the `overflow` property I did some googling to discover how well circulated this is, found the [google group for the project](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jquery-ui-layout) as well as other helpful information. For example, this exact question is in the [FAQ](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/tips.html#Draggables) (dealing with Draggables). Also see [working with drop-downs](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm#Drop-Downs) ...

The crux of this is it would be difficult/hacky so they wrote convenience methods `allowOverflow()` and `resetOverflow()` to help manage it.

Best of luck.